# How to call encodeWithCoder

Tags: objective-c, ios, serialization, nscoder

Possibly a nooby question - how is `encodeWithCoder` called? I need to use this to save objects in files on the iphone, I am just unsure of how it is actually called. Do I have to manually call it? If so, what do I use as input for the `NScoder` argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don’t call it yourself, you use [NSKeyedArchiver](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead:

```
NSData *serialized = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:foo];
```

Where `foo` is your object that conforms to `NSCoding`. There’s also a method to save the archived object directly to a file.

Comment: But does that mean if I wanted to archive something like a simple NSArray it would have to conform to NSCoding? This seems a bit overcomplicated to me.

Comment: I'm unable to edit the post, but it's archivedDataWithRootObject not archiveDataWithRootObject